# Retrofit generic type call method

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, retrofit2

Is it possible to create generic type of calls
for example

```
@POST("/service/")
fun<T> startRequest(@Body loginReq: Any): Call<T>
```

then just call it like this

```
val request = api.startRequest<MyModel_1>(loginReq)
```

when I write like this and run the method, it says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method return type must not include a type variable or wildcard: retrofit2.Call<T>
```

Comment: Did you see the following? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327048/retrofit-method-return-wildcard and https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2012 ?

Comment: Didn't the code you've posted work? What kind of error did it produce?

Comment: @voddan unfortunately not, error log is : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method return type must not include a type variable or wildcard: retrofit2.Call<T> " would be great

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate function with `@JvmSuppressWildcards`

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit(2.6.3) needs to know the types at compile time, when the annotation is being processed. So I don't think it's possible at all to use a generic if Retrofit won't support it in the future.